# C# - Dynamically created controls overlapping

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I'm creating a notepad type of application which has the tab functionality.

I have a MenuStrip at the top and I'm creating the TabControl, its TabPages and the RichTextBoxes at run-time and I have set the DockStyle of the TabControl as Fill. My problem is when I run the program the TabContol appears **under** the MenuStrip. It looks like this,

[image]

when it *should* look like this, **below** the MenuStrip. (for this screenshot only I added the TabControl at design time)

[image]

I think the reason is the TabControl gets created on the form before the MenuStrip does. How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx).

```
form1.Controls.SetChildIndex(tabControl1, 0);
```